# Add (eds.) to Special Issue's Journal authors biblatex

Tags: biblatex, journal

I am writing a thesis using LaTeX and I use Data from NEPS (German Panel study). Using it, I have to cite a Special Issue of a Journal. My problem is that I can not work out how to add "(eds.)" right after the authors' names.

**A minimal Working Example**

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % 

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, dashed=false, hyperref = auto, firstinits=true, indexing=cite, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{lit.bib}

@article{NEPS,
    title={Education as a Lifelong Process – The German National Educational Panel Study (NEPS)},
    author={Blossfeld, H.-P. and Roßbach, H.-G. and Von Maurice, J. {(Hrsg.)}}, 
    journal={Zeitschrift für Erziehungswissenschaft: Sonderheft 14},
    year={2011}
}

@article{NEPS2,
    issuetitle={Education as a Lifelong Process – The German National Educational Panel Study (NEPS)},
    editor={Blossfeld, H.-P. and Roßbach, H.-G. and Von Maurice, J.}, 
    journal={Zeitschrift für Erziehungswissenschaft: Sonderheft 14},
    year={2011}
}

\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{lit.bib}


\begin{document}

\cite{NEPS}
\cite{NEPS2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It now looks as follows (for \cite{NEPS}):

```
Blossfeld, H.-P., Roßbach, H.-G. & Von Maurice, J. ( (2011). Education as a Lifelong
Process – The German National Educational Panel Study (NEPS). Zeitschrift für Erziehungswissenschaft:
Sonderheft 14.
```

and for \cite{NEPS2}

```
(2011). Zeitschrift für Erziehungswissenschaft: Sonderheft 14 : Education as a Lifelong
Process – The German National Educational Panel Study (NEPS). H.-P. Blossfeld,
H.-G. Roßbach & J. Von Maurice (Hrsg.).
```

However, I want it to look like this:

```
Blossfeld, H.-P., Roßbach, H.-G. & Von Maurice, J. (Hrsg.) (2011). Education as a Lifelong
Process – The German National Educational Panel Study (NEPS). Zeitschrift für Erziehungswissenschaft:
Sonderheft 14.
```

How can I make LaTeX let the "(Hrsg.)/(eds.)" be added after the journal's authors when written in the authors' field? Or how can I reformat if using the field `issuetitle`?

Comment: I made the example compilable by moving the `\documentclass` line to the correct spot. The MWE was otherwise very useful, but obvious errors like this are always a bit of a red flag since they suggest that the MWE was not compiled as shown or that if it was compiled as shown blatant error messages were ignored.

Comment: Oh... you're right, that ist indeed the case, I copied it from a nested tex-structure. I will run the MWE the next time. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the type `@periodical` for entire issues of a journal. The journal name then goes into the `title` field and the title of the issue into `issuetitle`. I had some difficulty finding the right spot for the "Sonderheft 14", so the MWE has two examples, one where it is in the (possibly semantically nicer) `number` field and one where it is in the `issuetitle`.

Editors should never be placed in the `author` field if they are not authors and adding `(Hrsg.)` or the like is likely to go wrong because Biber/BibTeX will try to parse it as part of the name(s) in the field (that could only be avoided by placing the entire name in a pair of braces, but then the name is not split up in family and given name). Fortunately, `@periodical` supports and shows the `editor` field just as we want here.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp,
            dashed=false, giveninits=true,
            indexing=cite,]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@periodical{NEPS,
  issuetitle = {Education as a Lifelong Process --
                The German National Educational Panel Study (NEPS)},
  number     = {Sonderheft 14},
  editor     = {Blossfeld, H.-P. and Roßbach, H.-G. and Von Maurice, J.},
  title      = {Zeitschrift für Erziehungswissenschaft},
  year       = {2011},
}
@periodical{NEPS2,
  issuetitle = {Sonderheft 14:
                Education as a Lifelong Process -- 
                The German National Educational Panel Study (NEPS)},
  editor     = {Blossfeld, H.-P. and Roßbach, H.-G. and Von Maurice, J.},
  title      = {Zeitschrift für Erziehungswissenschaft},
  year       = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{NEPS,NEPS2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Blossfeld, H.-P., H.-G. Roßbach und J. Von Maurice, Hrsg. (2011a). Zeitschrift für Erziehungswissenschaft Sonderheft 14: Education as a Lifelong Process – The German National Educational Panel Study (NEPS).//Blossfeld, H.-P., H.-G. Roßbach und J. Von Maurice, Hrsg. (2011b). Zeitschrift für Erziehungswissenschaft: Sonderheft 14: Education as a Lifelong Process – The German National Educational Panel Study (NEPS).]

---

With

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}
```

you get parentheses around the "Hrsg.".

Comment: Thank you, that did indeed solve the (Hrsg.) problem!